# I need to find Variance of stochastic process $X_{t} = \int_{0}^{t} W^{+}_{s}dW_{s}$

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, variance

$W_{t}$ is a wiener process and $a^{+} = max (a, 0)$
So far I've had one thought. Use Ito's formula somehow. Here's what I got:
For $F(t, X(t)) = x^{2}$
$$
\left(\int_{0}^{t}W^{+}_{s}dW_{s}\right)^{2} = \int_{0}^{t}\left(W^{+}\right)^{2}_{s}dt
+2 * \int_{0}^{t}\left(\int_{0}^{t}W^{+}_{s}dW_{s}\right)W^{+}_{s}dW_{s}
$$

Which is not much better, but somewhat of an equation.
Though I might be in the wrong woods here, trying to find the integral, when I should be focusing on finding the variance directly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By defintion $\mathbb{E} (\int_0^t W_s^+dW_s)=0$, so we only need to compute the second moment. This follows easily from usage of the Ito Isometry formula: We have that:
$$\mathbb{E} (\int_0^t W_s^+dW_s)^2=\mathbb{E}\int_0^t (W_s^+)^2ds=\int_0^t \mathbb{E}(W_s^+)^2ds$$
We now note that we have that $W_s\sim s^{1/2}W_1$ so that:
$$\int_0^t\mathbb{E} (W_s^+)^2sds=\mathbb{E} (W_1^+)^2\int_0^tsds=\mathbb{E} (W_1^+)^2\frac{1}{2}t^2$$

To compute the remaining term, we have note that as $W_1\sim \cal{N}(0,1)$, we have that:
$$\mathbb{E} (W_1^+)^2=\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E} W_1^2=\frac{1}{2}$$
so that in total we have that:
$$\sigma=\frac{1}{4}t^2$$

Comment: Well, I have a question. Why is $E\left(W_{1}^{+}\right)^{2} = \frac{1}{2}EW_{1}^{2}$?

Comment: @vowchick It is clear that $\mathrm{sign}(W_1)$ and $|W_1|$ are independent. Thus we see that: $\mathbb{E} (W_1^+)^2= \mathbb{E} (W_1)^2 I(\mathrm{sign}(W_1)=1)=\mathbb{P}(\mathrm{sign}(W_1)=1)\mathbb{E}(W_1)^2=\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}(W_1)^2$,

Comment: Thank you very much! Everything is pretty much clear now. One last question, why do we need to express $W_{s}^{+}$ as $s^{\frac{1}{2}}W_{1}^{+}$? Can't we just say that: $E\left(W_{s}^{+}\right)^{2}=\frac{1}{2}E\left(W_{s}\right)^{2}$?